# Have pi 4b 8GB cannot hookup to wi-fi, lists all signals

Tags: wifi, security

Have new pi 4b 8GB, can not connect to Wi-Fi, will list all available signals including when I hot-spot my phone. Even with the right security codes will try but never connect. Have tried the latest Raspian and Mate Ubuntu o/s on different 32G cards, same results. Works fine if I tag it and it's all updated on both o/s's Lost, asking for help please, exhausted all my searches.

Comment: what does "Works fine if I tag it" mean? if it works when you "tag it" .... then "tag it" is the answer I guess

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. I can see all Wi-Fi sources on my PI4b, can join any of them, even connect to hotspot—except for my main home network. When I installed RaspbianOS, I used Balena Etcher to flash the SD card. During initial Etcher config it asked for Wi-Fi information, which I thought would make things easier…nope. I'm wondering if we both have a similar problem, where the configuration files became corrupted during setup.

Comment: Thanks, have tried erasing and reinstalling two different O.S's several times, which are on different cards so kind of cancelled out any corruption issues.